# Aframe VR : Eyeoffset Settings

Tags: camera, aframe, webvr, stereoscopy

This [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGCSJ.jpg) gets loaded in my **Oneplus 6** phone and is creating problem with the ***Stereoscopic vision***, no one is able to create focus with such a **high offset** between left & right eyes.

Can anyone help me out in setting the eyeoffset parameters, since i haven't been able to figure them out neither on **Aframe.io** documentation nor **Github**

Or is there something that i can do from **THREE.js Camera**

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for OnePlus 6 (A6000) are missing from the webvr-polyfill [device database](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill-dpdb/blob/master/dpdb-formatted.json). You can fork the [webvr-polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill) and database, add your device (you need to know dpi and bezel width) and see if the problem is solved in the examples. A-Frame will pick it up when we bump the polyfill version on next release. In the meantime you can do your own A-Frame build pointing to your `webvr-polyfill` fork.

Comment: I am unsatisfied with the way AFRAME is rendering left & right eye.
I want **both views exactly same** or with **very less offset**

Comment: A-Frame uses the database I pointed out to get each device parameters (dpi, bezel width) and adjust stereo rendering accordingly. OnePlus 6 does not have an entry yet in the database and A-Frame is not able to adjust the view to that particular display. If you can submit a PR to that repository it will be appreciated.

Comment: How can i trick AFRAME **not to use 3D** stereo rendering at all.
I mean **both left & right eyeviews** should be **same**

Comment: Views cannot be the same. you have to change the perspective of each eye to account for eye separation. Not sure I understand your request. The proper solution to your issue is adding the info of your device to the webvr-polyfill database as described above.

Comment: Alright, I am adding Oneplus 6 parameters
But still on other devices like **Redmi Note 4** , the separation I get is annoying for my audience. I built a native app with **2 webviewers side by side**.
Thats what i want with AFRAME settings,
There are so many things given like **fov, max, min** etc,
I think these settings can be somewhat handled with **THREE.js stereocomponent** which i have found to do something with **projectionMatrix** for both eye views